# Convert string into list of unique permutations containing 1 to length(string) elements in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, permutation

I'm try to split a string into the unique permutations of characters that compose the string.

```
strings <- c("DOG", "CAT", "BALL")

string   length  output

DOG      3       D, O, G, DO, DG, OG, DOG
CAT      3       C, A, T, CA, CT, AT, CAT
BALL     4       B, A, L, BA, BL, BAL
```

I've been trying to use the permutation function, but am unsure about how to apply it to a data frame.

Comment: Are you only using unique values? What if you had something like `mama` what would be the results?

Comment: It would be MA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach. Use `strsplit` to break each string up into individual (and unique) letters. Then for each set of letters, go through from 1 to the length of the string using `seq_along`, and look at combinations of letters with `combn`. The results are put into a list for each combination and then pasted together.

```
strings <- c("DOG", "CAT", "BALL")

data.frame(
  string = strings,
  length = nchar(strings),
  output = sapply(strings,
       function(s) { 
         x <- unique(strsplit(s, "")[[1]])
         toString(
           paste(
             sapply(
               do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) combn(x, i, list))), 
               paste, 
               collapse = "")
             )
           )
       }
  ), 
row.names = NULL)
```

**Output**

```
  string length                   output
1    DOG      3 D, O, G, DO, DG, OG, DOG
2    CAT      3 C, A, T, CA, CT, AT, CAT
3   BALL      4 B, A, L, BA, BL, AL, BAL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
fun <- function(x){
  y <- unique(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])
  toString(unlist(sapply(seq(y), combn, x = y, paste0, collapse = "")))
}

data.frame(strings, length=nchar(strings), output=sapply(strings,fun,USE.NAMES = FALSE))
 strings length                   output
1     DOG      3 D, O, G, DO, DG, OG, DOG
2     CAT      3 C, A, T, CA, CT, AT, CAT
3    BALL      4 B, A, L, BA, BL, AL, BAL
```